# Lindeberg CLT application

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of independent Random Variables with
$$\mathbb{P}(X_k = -1) = \mathbb{P}(X_k = 1) = \frac{1 - 2^k}{2}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X_k = 2^k) = \mathbb{P}(X_k = -2^k) = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} $$

How can I show the CLT holds? Tried to verify Lindeberg's Condition without success.

Comment: I can see applying Borel-Cantelli Lemma that there will be a finite number of times where $|X_k| \neq 1$, but it's not clear to me how to verify the CLT holds following this fact.

Comment: One neat way to show this is to start from independent random variables $(Y_k)$ and $(Z_k)$ with $P(Y_k=1)=P(Y_k=-1)=\frac12$ and $P(Z_k=2^k)=\frac1{2^k}=1-P(Z_k=1)$, then $X_k=Y_kZ_k$ has the distribution you want and, by the easy Borel-Cantelli lemma, $Z_k\ne1$ for finitely many $k$, almost surely. Thus, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY_k+R_n$ where the CLT applies to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY_k$ and $R_n\to0$ almost surely. This allows to conclude.

Comment: And, to build $(Y_k)$ and $(Z_k)$, define $Y_k=\mathrm{sign}(X_k)$ and $Z_k=|X_k|$ (but then a task is to prove that indeed $(Y_k,Z_k)$ is independent, for every $k$).

Answer (score -2):

First, use Borel-Cantelli Lemma to show that $\mathbb{P}[|X_k|>1,~\text{for some}~k\geq N]\leq 1/2^{N-1}$. Then, use the distributions of $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{\tilde{S_n}}{\sqrt{n}}$, and show the difference between them. Here $\tilde{S_n}=\sum_{i=1}^n\tilde{X_i}$ and $\tilde{X_k}$ satisfies $\mathbb{P}[\tilde{X_k}=1]=\mathbb{P}[\tilde{X_k}=-1]=1/2$.

There are three steps to show that.

Step 1, for any given $N$, there exists a $M>N$, such that $\frac{|S_n-\bar{S_n}|}{\sqrt{n}}<1/2^{N-1}$ for any $n>M$ while $\omega\in\Omega\backslash\mathcal{A}_N$. Here $\mathcal{A}_N\triangleq\{|X_k|>1 ~\text{for some}~k\geq N\}$.

Step 2, notice that $\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{A}_N]\leq 1/2^{N-1}$. Then you get $\mathbb{P}[\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq x]\leq \mathbb{P}[\frac{\tilde{S_n}}{\sqrt{n}}\leq x+1/2^{N-1}]+1/2^{N-1}$, as well as $\mathbb{P}[\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq x]\geq \mathbb{P}[\frac{\tilde{S_n}}{\sqrt{n}}\leq x-1/2^{N-1}]-1/2^{N-1}$.

Step 3, let $n$ tend $\infty$, and notice that $N$ can be arbitrary natural number. Then you can obtain the conclusion.

Comment: Sorry but the upper bound $\mathbb{P}[|X_k|>1,~\text{for some}~k\geq N]\leq 1/2^{N-1}$ is irrelevant and does not involve Borel-Cantelli lemma. On the other hand, Borel-Cantelli lemma **is** useful to solve the question.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but do you consider that your post answers the question? For example, what are the random variables $\tilde X_k$? Surely not every sequence $(\tilde X_k)$ with the correct distribution is suitable?